# Which instruction at which address calls the address 0x1a95 or the address 0x204a in the following program or rather smart contract?

Tags: disassembly, disassemblers, byte-code, control-flow-graph, call-graph

The Ethereum Virtual Machine uses a Virtual Instruction Set flavored for transaction processing that doesn’t use any registers and where all opcodes are a single byte long and have a single ABI for all the programming languages used (https://ethervm.io/#opcodes similar to the Java Virtual Machine from Oracle).
There’s no executable format being used as everything runs at bare metal. The primary programming languages for the platform doesn’t even provide a standard library (but only keywords which translate into high level opcodes).

**Despite Ethereum being the second most valued cryptocurrency for years,** I was unable to find a tool able to draw call graphs for that architecture or rather, I did find one which only treats jumps from addresses if written on the stack through `PUSH` instructions.

So is there a tool fully supporting the Ethereum Virtual Machine’s bytecode (not half) for drawing call graphs or [which instruction at which address calls the address `0x1a95` or the address `0x204a` in this program](http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/Uniswap.svg) (the blocks are at the top right bottom)?

The full bytecode without any attempt to format it into blocks is here:

```
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
```

Both a fully working tool (unlike the current one) for the problem or the answer to it can be the answer.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you looking for a tool, or for someone to answer the question in your title?

Comment: @tmr232 the tool would essenitally give the answer in the title, so both are acceptable answers.